# Entity framework OptimisticConcurrencyException issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, addition, optimistic-concurrency

I'm using entity framework 4. In a form, I have a `DataGridView` with a list of entities assigned as a `DataSource`. Then, I have two buttons. One that deletes the last entity(`historial_borrar`) of the list(`lista_historial_prestamo`), that is actually the first row of the `DataGridView`:

```
Historial_estado_prestamo historial_borrar = 
    (Historial_estado_prestamo)dgv_Historial_estado_prestamo.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;

dgv_Historial_estado_prestamo.DataSource = null;

lista_historial_prestamo.Remove(historial_borrar);

historial_borrar.Prestamo.Estado_prestamo = 
     lista_historial_prestamo.OrderByDescending(x => x.fecha_hora).First().Estado_prestamo;

db.DeleteObject(historial_borrar);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Then, the other button, adds a new entity to the database.

```
Historial_estado_prestamo historial_nuevo = new Historial_estado_prestamo();

historial_nuevo.fecha_hora = DateTime.Now;

historial_nuevo.Estado_prestamo = db.Estado_prestamo.Where(x => x.id_estado_prestamo == 2)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();

prestamo_seleccionado.Historial_estado_prestamo.Add(historial_nuevo);

dgv_Historial_estado_prestamo.DataSource = null;

lista_historial_prestamo.Add(historial_nuevo);

lista_historial_prestamo = lista_historial_prestamo.OrderByDescending(x => x.fecha_hora)
                                                   .ToList();
prestamo_seleccionado.Estado_prestamo =   
    lista_historial_prestamo.FirstOrDefault().Estado_prestamo;
db.SaveChanges();
```

I obviously refresh the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`(`dgv_Historial_estado_prestamo`) every time a button is clicked.

The idea is that if I add one, I just can delete that one after it.

And if I add one, and then delete that one. I get an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`.

I don´t really know why! I `SaveChanges()` every time I delete the object or add it to the database. I also delete it from the `datasource` list.

I get this exception just when I delete the object after adding it.

I have been reading some posts and tried this:

```
{
    Historial_estado_prestamo historial_borrar = 
        (Historial_estado_prestamo)dgv_Historial_estado_prestamo.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;

    dgv_Historial_estado_prestamo.DataSource = null;

    lista_historial_prestamo.Remove(historial_borrar);

    historial_borrar.Prestamo.Estado_prestamo = 
         lista_historial_prestamo.OrderByDescending(x => x.fecha_hora)
                                 .First()
                                 .Estado_prestamo;
    db.DeleteObject(historial_borrar);
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, historial_borrar);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I don't have the exception with this code, but when I close and reopen that form, all the objects that I have deleted are actually there.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".